# What are these notes in an advanced violin piece?

Tags: notation, rhythm, violin, musescore

I am rewriting [this](http://ks.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/8/8f/IMSLP05504-Ernst_erlkoenig.pdf) for two violins but am having a little trouble with the very first measure.  They look like some weird sort of triplet.  How do I enter the notes into a music editor?  I've never seen that kind of syntax!

[image]
[image]

Comment: They _are_  triplets, it's just the triplet marks are left out. It's not too uncommon as [seen here](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/41597/how-is-it-that-12-eighth-notes-fit-in-a-measure-labeled-as-common-time). Just mark them as triplets in musescore.

Comment: What is your musical background/training?

Comment: violin lessons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dom has it right. They'd just be written as triplets with only the top or bottom notes present. You could enter them into the music editor the way you'd do any other triplet, with or without the triplet mark.

---

So, as far as stuff like left hand pizz, (which my computer keeps trying to say is "left hand pizza") it is currently not a possibility in Musescore to specify left hand pizzicato, but you can certainly tell it to perform pizzicato and write left hand in in the notes. (See: https://musescore.org/en/node/12183)

Triplets can be input with the information present here: https://musescore.org/en/node/11186

Which looks like this:

[image: Triplets!]
[image: More Triplets!]

Although, as Tim said, it's possible that you'd want to use 12/8 instead of this method.

Comment: and i would enter them as eighth notes?

Comment: ok, entered!  now I have the new image in the question.  how do I make this look like the original?

Comment: @dalearn Not quite... Let me see here... Just a moment, I'll do it myself in Muscore and show you so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I'd swap them over, so the top line consists of the top notes. It could be written in 12/8, or 4/4 with a comment at the top stating a crotchet = 3 quaver triplets.

Comment: also, how do i put in left hand pizz?

Comment: @Tim is probably right. I was perhaps a bit hasty with my answer. As far as stuff like left hand pizz and whatnot, it really varies with the editor you're using. I understand that the OP is using musescore... So let me take a look-see...

Comment: @Tim, please turn that into an answer!  I converted everything to 12/8 and it is MUCH easier!

Comment: I'm not sure you need to write *anything* for LH pizz -- it's pretty obvious to the performer in most cases that the bow hand is unavailable for the pizzicato notes in question.  BTW,  I'm getting hungry for a left-hand pizza!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Fair point, I've seen places, particularly in modern music, where left hand pizz is not specified, but I've also seen places where it is, especially when it's because you're alternating between pizz and arco without much of a break, but some naive musician may attempt to do a traditional pizz anyway. Think Fantasia from Boy Paganini, where in most copies, "left hand pizza" is notated by a little cross over the notes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to GeneralNuisance for jogging my memory.  The [Dolmetsch](http://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm) chart lists  a "+" sign over the note as indicating Left-hand Pizz.  So two suggestions:
1) place a text "+" where you want it in Musescore,
2) switch to Lilypond :-)

ETA for non-google people: [lilypond](http://lilypond.org/)

Comment: what is lillypond?

Comment: @dalearn see edit

Comment: Musescore 3 has a "+" for "mute" in the category Articulations, so unless you're concerned about how the playback sounds (which I don't think you should as it doesn't quite reflect how it might sound when played by actual human), you could simply use those as the l.h. pizz notation.