# Examples of pictures using notated music

Tags: sheet-music, classical-music, avant-garde

My teacher was talking about a college professor she had that had a picture drawn out that was drawn using music. It was a playable piece but looked complicated. I'd like to see an example and can't find any online

Comment: Hi, welcome.  You will find (in general, not just here) that providing an example of the picture and a detailed description of how the music produced the picture.  For example, I know of "show off" cases where a complicated fourier transform dataset was converted back to sound and the resultant signal, written in spiral format, produced a picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you read Graphic Scores?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23725/how-do-you-read-graphic-scores)

Comment: It sounds like you may be talking about some form of [graphical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_notation_(music)).

Comment: Would piano roll notation a la Synthesia count? Because that's where I've seen the majority of these pictures made out of music.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you mean, but there is the piece „Ode an das Ruhrgebiet“ by Marc Vogler which is a playable piece, but the score sheet depicts the headframe of a [coal mine in Essen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zollverein_Coal_Mine_Industrial_Complex), Germany. You can see an image on [the composer's page](http://www.marc-vogler.de/Info/Aktuelle-Projekte). ([Larger version](https://homepage-creator.telekom.de/-/CMTOI/cm4all/com/widgets/PhotoToi/15/38/51/98/1517729a6f1/scale_1200_0%3Bdonotenlarge/1517729a6f1)).